# Main Clause + [; vs .]+ Conjunctive Adverb + , + Main Clause

Tags: adverbs, conjunctions

I have read on more that a website that a conjunctive adverb is preceded by a semicolon. As far as I remember, however, I have seen more often than not a period used instead of the semicolon. Even on the same Web page below a period is used when a semicolon, they claim, is called for,

> Notice, however, that you need a semicolon, not a comma, to connect
>   the two clauses:
>
> Main Clause + ; + Conjunctive Adverb + , + Main Clause.
>
> ... The cat ate a bowlful of tuna; then, to the squirrels' delight,
>   the fat feline fell asleep in the rocking chair.

On the same page you find an example at odds with their advice or the rule they set.

> At 10 a.m., Paul was supposed to be taking his biology midterm.
>   Instead, he was flirting with the pretty waitress at the coffee house.

Source: [The Conjunctive Adverb. Recognize a conjunctive adverb when you see one](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/conjunctiveadverb.htm)

Answer (score 1):

According to yourdictionary.com, you can use a period or a semicolon.

> **Correct Punctuation**
>
> To correctly punctuate a conjunctive adverb, a writer will **use a
>   semicolon or *period*** at the end of the first
>   independent clause. The conjunctive adverb is then used followed by a
>   comma and the next independent clause.

Source: [List of Conjunctive Adverbs](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/adverbs/list-of-conjunctive-adverbs.html)